# How to check if an element is visible in Java Script by using its name?

Tags: javascript, jquery

At the moment I can look up an element by Id and check if it's visible, like this...

```
this.CheckFormField = function (fieldId) {
    return ($("#" + fieldId).length > 0 && $("#" + fieldId).is(":visible"));
}
```

How do I achieve the same result by using the elements name?

Comment: I'd guess you don't need the length check here and that `is` on an empty selection would return false.

Comment: `return ($('[name='+ fieldName +']).length > 0 && $('[name='+ fieldName +']).is(":visible"));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To filter on attributes, you can use the `[]` notation. So if you want all elements with the name `test`, you use `[name=test]`.

```
this.CheckFormField = function (fieldId) {
    return ($("[name=" + fieldId + "]").length > 0 && $("[name=" + fieldId + "]").is(":visible"));
}
```